# No me carga los datos de mi base de datos en mi jsp?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, netbeans, jdbc

[image]

La base de datos esta de forma local tengo entendido que se le coloca las librerias ya estan colocadas del jdbc y el jar de mysql pero no jala los datos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tiene tres errores muy importantes:

1. El fin del `try/catch` es mostrar el `stacktrace` para saber dónde ocurre una excepción y por qué ocurre.
2. Le falta un colon ":" después del `jdbc:mysql`
3. Hay espacios en los strings tanto de la url de conexión como en el nombre de la clase que le trae y pone a funcionar la librería JDBC.

Su `try/catch` no hace nada ni muestra nada si atrapa un `Exception` ..

Intente cambiando la url de conexión de

```
jdbc:mysql//localhost/db?etc...
```

a

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?etc...
```

Normalmente se debería especificar el puerto también:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?etc...
```

Si ésto no le soluciona su error, (y aunque lo solucione!) agrege:

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

A su `catch(Exception e){ .... aca ...}`

Si deja la url sin corregir le saldrá un

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:mysql//localhost/etc...

**Importante que no deje espacios en la url, de lo contrario también le saldrá ésta excepción**

Si deja los espacios en el `forName("[espacio]com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` le botará la siguiente excepción:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Su código final debería ser algo por el estilo:

```
<%
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(" jdbc:mysql://localhost/cursosjsp?user=root");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from usuarios");

        while (rs.next()) {
            // etc ...
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvió de mucho ... no me había percatado de ese pequeño error